# @rollup/plugin-typescript TS2307: Cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, node-modules, circleci

I'm following [this guide](https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-create-and-publish-a-react-component-library-2oe) to make a react component library for my company. I set up all as the guide and then tried running `npm rollup -c`. It works on my machine (it builds without errors).

But when I try plugging it into CircleCI (the tool we use for builds), it throws this error:

[image]

The config is all the same, the server uses Linux and the node version is the same. Is there something I'm missing? Or something I can test?

Comment: Does CircleCI let you choose which location (path) the build is being run from? The path probably needs to be the equivalent to the location from which you're running the build locally.

Comment: What you mean the path? In my local machine I have the project in a folder on my desktop. But the project structure is the same, can somehow this affect the build?

Comment: By path I mean from where the build command is being run.